# How to get Value of multiple select options with same class and name

Tags: javascript, php, html-select, default-value

I am trying to get the value of the selected option. However, there are 2 different select menus, using the same name and class. I want to be able to pull the text inside the value.

I already know which select option they choose, but I can't seem to get the value of the option.

This is the HTML

```
<div id="single_course" style="display: none;">
    <SELECT class="form-control" name="course_choice">
        <OPTION value="1">Value 1</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2">Value 2</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3">Value 3</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</div>
<div id="2day_course" style="display: none;">
    <SELECT class="form-control" name="course_choice">
        <OPTION value="1">Value 1</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2">Value 2</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3">Value 3</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</div>
```

This the JS Code

```
var course_choice = $('#register select[name=course_choice]').value;
```

Your advice is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you not able to change their names?

Comment: Yes - I can change their names. I am just trying to figure out the easiest way to do this! @AstroCB I have access to all the code, so if you have a suggestion, please post it. Thanks

Comment: I was just wondering because it would be easier if they had different names because you could reference them separately. However, the answers posted below get around that.

Comment: Ok. So if I seperate the names, then will my above code work? @AstroCB

Comment: I believe so; also, classes are generally used for grouping similar things together (as you have done), but names are generally unique to each element. The reason why it doesn't work now is because `name="course_choice"` references two elements, which is why sjkm's answer below works: it selects each of the two objects referenced.

Comment: Cool. Great to know! Appreciate your help! I will try the below and then go for seperate names if it proves difficult, because I still have to pull the js and send it through PHP and I suck at writing arrays @AstroCB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var course_choices = $('select[name="course_choice"]');

var course_choice1 = course_choices.eq(0).val();
var course_choice2 = course_choices.eq(1).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot get the values of both. So, you can get it as an array. You can do like this:

```
<div id="single_course" style="display: none;">
    <SELECT class="form-control" name="course_choice[]">
        <OPTION value="1">Value 1</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2">Value 2</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3">Value 3</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</div>
<div id="2day_course" style="display: none;">
    <SELECT class="form-control" name="course_choice[]">
        <OPTION value="1">Value 1</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2">Value 2</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3">Value 3</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</div>
```

Or, if you cannot change the HTML, then you can do this way suggested by [sjkm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435406/sjkm):

```
var course_choices = $('select[name="course_choice"]');

var course_choice[0] = course_choices.eq(0).val();
var course_choice[1] = course_choices.eq(1).val();
```

Comment: please do not just copy

Comment: @sjkm Sorry but there's no other way. I will credit you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do I have to put the numbers (0 & 1) in the select name. So for example: name="course_choice[0]" & name="course_choice[1]"? Or no? @sjkm

Comment: It is up to you. You don't need. But putting it doesn't matter. Gives the same result @KingOptimizer!

Comment: I am asking, because I will then need to take the JS variable and display it in php format through a POST @PraveenKumar

Comment: If you are displaying it to a PHP file, then it will go as an array. Which means, `course_choice => Array (2, 3)`. Something like this!

Comment: So how would I write the PHP code for that? I have it as $_POST[course_choices]. Man - this is difficult! @PraveenKumar

Comment: Yes. That's the way! @KingOptimizer! :) `$_POST["course_choices"][0]`

Comment: Its displaying ARRAY when I used your code! @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// array of selected options (array items are dom objects)
var course_choice = $('#register select[name=course_choice] option:selected');

// extract option's value with jquery
console.log( $(course_choice[0]).val() );
console.log( $(course_choice[1]).val() );

// ... or without query
console.log( course_choice[0].value );
console.log( course_choice[1].value );
```

Answer (score 0):

working fine for me :

```
    <SELECT class="form-control select_addon" name="course_choice[]">
    var mang_addon_cart = [];
    var course_choice = $('.select_addon option:selected');
    for(var i = 0; i < course_choice.length; i++){
        var val_addon = course_choice.eq(i).val();
        var name_addon = course_choice.eq(i).data('name');
      mang_addon_cart.push({
        giatri : val_addon,
        name : name_addon
      });
    }
    console.log(mang_addon_cart);
```